# Tailwind flex-row-reverse doesn't display spacing properly

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to get two versions of the navbar - one LTR and the other is RTL.
For that I am adding `flex-row-reverse` to the two necessary divs, but the space between the logo and the search bar disappears.

This is the LTR navbar without `flex-row-reverse`:

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
   <nav
    class="bg-gray-900 text-white px-4 py-3 flex items-center justify-between"
  >
    <div class="flex items-center space-x-4">
      <a href="#" class="text-white hover:text-gray-400">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
  <path d="M12 14l9-5-9-5-9 5 9 5z" />
  <path d="M12 14l6.16-3.422a12.083 12.083 0 01.665 6.479A11.952 11.952 0 0012 20.055a11.952 11.952 0 00-6.824-2.998 12.078 12.078 0 01.665-6.479L12 14z" />
<path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M12 14l9-5-9-5-9 5 9 5zm0 0l6.16-3.422a12.083 12.083 0 01.665 6.479A11.952 11.952 0 0012 20.055a11.952 11.952 0 00-6.824-2.998 12.078 12.078 0 01.665-6.479L12 14zm-4 6v-7.5l4-2.222" />
</svg>
      </a>
      <div class="lg:block relative">
        <input
          type="text"
          class="rounded bg-gray-700 placeholder-white w-72 px-3 py-1"
          placeholder="Search or jump to..."
        />
        <div class="absolute top-0 right-0 flex items-center h-full">
          <div
            class="
              border border-gray-600
              rounded
              text-xs text-gray-400
              px-2
              mr-2
            "
          >
            /
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

And this is the broken RTL version with no spacing between the logo and the search bar (when using `flex-row-reverse`):

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <nav
    class="bg-gray-900 text-white px-4 py-3 flex flex-row-reverse items-center justify-between"
  >
    <div class="flex flex-row-reverse items-center space-x-4">
      <a href="#" class="text-white hover:text-gray-400">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
  <path d="M12 14l9-5-9-5-9 5 9 5z" />
  <path d="M12 14l6.16-3.422a12.083 12.083 0 01.665 6.479A11.952 11.952 0 0012 20.055a11.952 11.952 0 00-6.824-2.998 12.078 12.078 0 01.665-6.479L12 14z" />
<path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M12 14l9-5-9-5-9 5 9 5zm0 0l6.16-3.422a12.083 12.083 0 01.665 6.479A11.952 11.952 0 0012 20.055a11.952 11.952 0 00-6.824-2.998 12.078 12.078 0 01.665-6.479L12 14zm-4 6v-7.5l4-2.222" />
</svg>
      </a>
      <div class="lg:block relative">
        <input
          type="text"
          class="rounded bg-gray-700 placeholder-white w-72 px-3 py-1"
          placeholder="Search or jump to..."
        />
        <div class="absolute top-0 right-0 flex items-center h-full">
          <div
            class="
              border border-gray-600
              rounded
              text-xs text-gray-400
              px-2
              mr-2
            "
          >
            /
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to tailwind documentation, [reference link](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/space#reversing-children-order)

> If your elements are in reverse order (using say `flex-row-reverse` or
> `flex-col-reverse`), use the `space-x-reverse` or `space-y-reverse`
> utilities to ensure the space is added to the correct side of each
> element.

So just add the class `space-x-reverse` in your code like this: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/m1n8hy2j/)

```
<div class="flex flex-row-reverse items-center space-x-4 space-x-reverse">
```

Comment: Thank you - that worked! I need to read the docs more carefully

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `gap-{size}` instead of `space-x` / `space-x-reverse` or `space-y` / `space-y-reverse`  to change the gap between both rows and columns in grid and flexbox layouts. [Refference](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/gap#setting-the-gap-between-elements)